# Spring Boot Integration Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have been trying to write a integration test for a small Spring boot Project that I have written but for some reason seem unable to get integration tests to work.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
package au.azzmosphere.integration;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {IntegrationTestConfiguration.class})
public class TestIntegration1 {
    @Test
    public void testDummy() {

    }
}
```

the configuration class has the following:

```
package au.azzmosphere.integration;

import au.azzmosphere.configuration.RobotAppConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration extends RobotAppConfig {
}
```

The code is consistently getting the following errors when I try to run the Integration Test from IntelliJ

```
14:54:01.537 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class au.azzmosphere.integration.TestIntegration1].
14:54:01.542 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.TestContext - @ContextConfiguration not found for class [class au.azzmosphere.integration.TestIntegration1].
14:54:01.549 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class au.azzmosphere.integration.TestIntegration1]: using defaults.
```

From gradle the following is returned

```
au.azzmosphere.integration.TestIntegration1 > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

The full stack trace is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.retrieveTestExecutionListeners(TestContextManager.java:171)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: can you paste fulll stack trace? Which class is not found?

Comment: I have added the full stack trace to the answer hope it helps.

Comment: CHeck this https://www.mkyong.com/spring/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-transaction-transactionexception/

Comment: Looks like the TestExecutionListeners automatically puts the TransactionalTestExecutionListener into the application if you the 'TestExecutionListeners' annotation is not used. I have now added the following

Comment: `@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})` and it has gotten rid of the original exception but has introduced a new one

Comment: ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@68837a77] to prepare test instance [au.azzmosphere.integration.TestIntegration1@2d554825]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not build an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.

Comment: I thought that this was taken care of by the SpringBoot annotation but may be wrong.

Comment: @gladiator I checked out that MyKong page, attempted to apply the suggestion and it worked some what, but still just progresses to the next exception that I am getting :( which is `16:03:56.893 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[TestContext@3dd3bcd testClass = TestIntegration1, locations = array<String>['classpath:/au/azzmosphere/integration/TestIntegration1-context.xml'], testInstance =`

Comment: Ok finally got somewhere, I removed the dependency injections all together.

Comment: `@TestExecutionListeners({})` and it now executes the dummy test,

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, :) The problem was that I did not have any TransactionDefinition defined because I didn't use it.  The default SpringBoot annotation attempts to inject it. The answer was to use @TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class}) which overrides the defaults and gets things going.